# regex match <... not <...>

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi I am using notepad++ and I need a regex witch match number 1 not number 2

```
number 1    <aaaaaa.


number 2   <aaaaaa.>
```

I tried this but it matches both of them not just number 1
I tried `<.*(?!.*\>)`

and im expect to be match just number 1 not number 2

Comment: Do you expect to match "number 1" or just "1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match only number 1:

```
^[^<\n>]*<[^\n<>]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^<\n>]*` Match optional chars other than a newline or `<` or `>`
- `<[^\n<>]*` Match `<` followed by 0+ occurrences of any char other than a newline or `<` or `>`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TCAFDn/1)

Or if you only want to match the single part:

```
<(?![^<>\n]*>).*
```

**Explanation**

- `<` Match literally
- `(?![^<>\n]*>)` Negative lookahead, assert no more occurrence of `>` to the right
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ol4f2U/1)